# Nested same direction collection views

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two nested UICollectionViews, both scrolling in the vertical direction. I need the outer collection view to scroll to it's max range first before allowing the inner collection view to scroll. The inner collection view should not be scrollable until the outer collection view has reached it's max range. Here's an example:

[image: nested scrollviews]

In the left diagram, a vertical drag inside of collection view B should move collection view A and collection view B should not be scrollable (but it still needs to be able to receive touches/taps). Once collection view A reaches it's max range (when collection view B gets to the top of the screen), then collection view B should scroll. This needs to work in one continuous motion.

I've attempted to toggle collection view B's scrollEnabled from collection view A's scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method, but this doesn't appear to be a viable solution because it doesn't work in one continuous motion (eg: The user needs to release and touch again after collection view B reaches the top of the screen).

What's the best way to implement this such that is works in one continuous motion?

My sample project is here: https://github.com/mbuff24/NestedCollectionViewExample

Comment: get the same problem, I use scrollViewDidScroll method, and manually scrolling the inner scrollview, but the scrolling seem very slow

Comment: Alright thanks. We ended up changing the design after all.